# How To Publish A Per Replica Enabled Sync Model Feature Service in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, replication

I have published a Feature Service (Sync Enabled) to our ArcGIS Server but I am only getting **`PerLayer`** Sync Model in the service

[image]

but I need to have Sync Per Replica Instead. like

[image]

I didn't see any thing available in ArcMap Service Editor Wizard regarding to this

[image]

Can you please let me know how I can enable the Per Replica Then?

Comment: Are you the owner of the data being hosted as a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your data set to archiving? If Yes, try to version the dataset, delete the old one and republish it. Check the "[supportsPerReplicaSync](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Create_Replica/02r3000000rp000000/)" on the feature service after publishing. It should be set to "true".

[image]